# Datanode denied communication with namenode - hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have installed HDFS in a 12 node cluster. It is deployed in EC2(AWS) instances. All these EC2 instances have 2 network interfaces - `eth0` and `eth1`. `eth1` has static IP address and `eth0` has an IP address which changes when instances are rebooted. Lets say `eth0`'s IP address is 'ABC' and `eth1`'s IP address is 'XYZ'. In my hosts file (/etc/hosts) I have made entries for all nodes FQDN and IP addresses (the IP address of `eth1`). For some reason when DataNodes try to connect to the NameNode it uses the IP address of `eth0` (which is 'ABC' in this case). It shows the below error and fails.

Error in LOGS is given below:

> Initialization failed for Block pool
>   BP-1423100917-*name_node_host*-1544213589860 (Datanode Uuid
>   160d6133-54f1-4a29-a6f0-0e52c0c59708) service to
>   *NAME_NODE_HOSTNAME*.net/*NAME_NODE_IP*:8022 Datanode denied communication with namenode because hostname cannot be resolved
>   (ip=ABC, hostname=ABC): DatanodeRegistration(XYZ,
>   datanodeUuid=160d6133-54f1-4a29-a6f0-0e52c0c59708, infoPort=50075,
>   infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020,
>   storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=cluster8;nsid=2080909946;c=0)

I have tried below options to fix this issue. But it did not work.

Setting the property `dfs.datanode.dns.interface` to `eth1` in both DataNode and NameNode and restarted the HDFS service. Also tried changing it only for DataNode or NameNode. (hdfs-site.xml)

Setting the property `dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check` to 'false' in both data nodes and NameNode and restarted the HDFS service. Also tried changing it only for DataNode or NameNode.(hdfs-site.xml)

Most of previous posts related to this error points to above mentioned parameters. But it did not work for me. Has anyone faced same issue?

Comment: I am facing similar issue while writing data via a java client from external network. The datanode hostname doesnt resolve correctly while trying to write the data block. For me the namenode returns the EC2 private IP rather than the public ip. I dont want a NAT or reverse dns to be put as layer in vpc, instead find a simpler way to resolve the host correctly in EC2.